# Painting Brand new concrete floor - is an acid wash necessary?

Tags: concrete, floor, paint

I just bought a newly constructed house that has a large (20x20) attached shop with a concrete floor.  I want to paint the floor.

I've looked at several sites on how to do this, and they all say to acid wash the floor before painting, but it seems that they assume there is oil on the floor.  I'm ready and willing to wash it, prime it (it doesn't need patching), and paint it, but I don't want to acid wash it, because there isn't enough ventilation in there to be safe --- just one small window, and a big door that goes to the house, not to the outside.

The floor (like the rest of the house) is brand new, so it should be clean and oil free, although I will mop it first anyway.  So is there really a need to acid wash it?  Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It all depends on what type of paint you're using; if it's meant to be used on bare/fresh concrete, it will give application instructions, and you deviate from those at your peril. (They don't tell you to do things to be annoying, but to improve the chance that their product will work well.)

Comment: Acid wash is for opening the surface to allow paint to bond. If fumes are a problem open the surface mechanically diamond abrasion or blast track  I will try to give an answer with some references later

Comment: A diluted Muratic acid and water solution will improve the bonding of epoxy paints by etching the surface slightly and removing cement dust when mopped up. New cement can be almost as bad as older cement because the surface has a fair amount of material that will flake off and not be as strong as a surface that has been etched. Muratic acid is not expensive and adding it to water is a 5 to 10% solution will make a better bonding surface. I have done this on almost all the floors I have covered and used stronger solutions for old surfaces that have contaminants followed by a fresh water rinse.

Comment: Thanks very much for the responses.  It seems that I was mistaken about the purpose of the acid wash; it's not just to clean up oil.

Comment: What a strange system; when you hit enter to go to a new line, it posts the comment, and now it won't let me edit it.  I was going to go on to say  I still don't want to use acid wash because of the ventilation concerns, so I guess I'll look into tile or some other solution that doesn't require it.  Thanks again for the responses.